# Should these two questions be considered duplicates?

Tags: discussion

It seems there is an incredible amount of overlap between these two questions.  Specifically, some of the answers in both may be useful for the other.

Does this qualify as a duplicate?  If so, is the policy to always select the newer question as a duplicate?

- [Troubles with SureFire plugin: -"The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ? "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585784/troubles-with-surefire-plugin-the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properl)
- [Strategy for debugging surefire "The forked VM terminated without saying properly goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20642673/strategy-for-debugging-surefire-the-forked-vm-terminated-without-saying-properl)

Comment: No, the policy is to select the *better* one. Having had longer to collect good answers, and get polished obviously increases the old questions chances to *be* that better question considerably. (If the dupe got an answer adding something new, don't forget to flag a mod for merging, with explicit reference.)

Comment: @Deduplicator: Thanks for the tip about *better*.  That's make good sense when I think about it.  And I didn't know about recco for merge on flag for mod.